# Split pasted text (textarea) for new lines

Tags: jquery

I would like to split a string, which has been pasted to a textarea, by every `,` and `,` to new lines. Also: After replaceing blank lines should be removed.

So this:

```
apple,bananas, tomatoes, ,anything.
```

Should get:

```
apple
bananas
tomatoes
anything.
```

My attempt:

```
$("#txtcomplaint").bind('paste', function(e) {
    var elem = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        var text = elem.val(); 
        $("#txtcomplaint").val(text.replace(', ', '\n').replace(',', '\n'));
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: so what is the problem with it? what result are you getting??

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu the timeout is required in some browsers as the updated text is not always available immediate after the `pate` event fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, you just need to also remove whitespace around the items and remove duplicated line breaks:

```
$("#txtcomplaint").bind('paste', function(e) {
    var elem = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        elem.val(function(i, val) {
            return $.trim(val.replace(/\s?,\s?/g, '\n').replace(/\n+/g, '\n'));
        });
    }, 20);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6uposvL6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var str="apple,bananas, tomatoes, ,anything";
    var lines = str.split(/,/);
    var texts = [];
    for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      if (/\S/.test(lines[i])) {
        texts.push($.trim(lines[i]));
      }
    }
    var n = texts.toString().split(",").join("\n");
    $("#txtcomplaint") .val(n);
```

Fiddle Demo-- http://jsfiddle.net/RahulB007/2cqxbu7v/